# How can I compare database from specified text

Tags: java, sql, compare

I want to compare each `resultset` from a database table, `students`, like this:

```
String gender = "";
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT gender FROM students;");
while (rs.next()) {
    gender = rs.getString("Gender");
}
if (gender.equals("Male")) {
    //not allowed
} else {
    //allowed  
}
```

however, the above code is not working.

Comment: I don't think you have posted enough of your code for us to provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: Would it not be best to filter in SQL? SELECT gender FROM students where Gender != 'Male';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `if else` under your `while` loop as mentioned here:

```
    while(rs.next()){
       gender = rs.getString("Gender");
       if(gender.equals("Male")){
           //not allowed
       }else{
           //allowed  
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are outside while loop, where you obtaining each result. You probably would like to move your if-else statement into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problems are as follows:

1: remove the second-to-last semicolon from this statement
    rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT gender FROM students;");

2: You call it 'gender' here:
   rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT gender FROM students;");
But you call it 'Gender' here (change it to 'gender'). Gender and gender are two different words.
    gender = rs.getString("Gender");

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to alter the query(if your business case allows/makes sense here) to get only gender!=Male. This will reduce select statement execution and cut looping through unwanted values.

Then as suggested by others, move the logic into the while loop so that logic is applied to all values satisfying the condition.

Comment: what do you mean by `!=` ?